# Remove fullwidth and half width charactors in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding

My DB does not support full width and half width chars. So I need to escape them before insertion.

I believe the range is U+FF00 to U+FFFF

so my function reads

```
function escapeZeroWidth(userInput){
    return (userInput ? userInput.replace(/[\uFF00-\uFFFF]/g, '') : userInput);
}
```

But this is not working as expected(not escapin chars).

Is there anything wrong in code?

Comment: Why are you doing this in Javascript? What does this have to do with database limitations? Why only "full-width characters", what about the other hundreds of thousands of Unicode characters out there? If you're accepting any sort of input, then make sure your database can handle it. If you expect only certain kinds of input, then validate and reject the input *on the server*. This question seems very misguided.

Comment: Sorry, I just read your question again. In your code it seems that you want to drop those characters, but the title of your question is 'Escape'. What do you want? What is your database?

Comment: Good point about other chars, but this needs to be a quick patch and we are having some problem for one or two chars only which are full width, though I am doing for all full width chars.

Comment: Yes I want it removed, thanks, edited the question title.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's FF00 - FFFE (but this is not important). I'd change it to something like this so you don't loose the ASCII characters:

```
return userInput.replace(/[\uFF00-\uFFFE]/g, function (char) {
    if (char >= '\uFF00' && char <= '\uFF5E') {
        return String.fromCharCode(
            ' '.charCodeAt(0) + 
            (char.charCodeAt(0) - '\uFF00'.charCodeAt(0)));
    }
    return '';
});
```

But when you say it is not working, maybe you have to deal with other characters than full-width as well.

Comment: You may have a look at the source-code of [node-codepoint](https://github.com/koichik/node-codepoint/) and read http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes and http://www.2ality.com/2013/09/javascript-unicode.html

Comment: Yes good point, there may be other chars then full-width, actually is a quick patch, for a particular char and that char is a full-width char.